# how to modify pip install path on mac os 10.10

Tags: python, django, macos, environment-variables, pip

I want to use python3.4 as the default version and install extra packages to python3 by pip or easy_install. I have installed python3.3 and python3.4 on my mac.

To change the default python version, aka, `python` command will go to python3.4 instead python2.7, I added a file called `.bash_aliases` with `alias python='python'` in it, then `source` the file. The method works until I restart terminal. Moreover I added `export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4/"` into `.bash_profile` then `source` it, but the version doesn't change.

I have these environment variables set up in `.bash_profile`, but don't know how to change even after googling and having tried different strategies. Some lines in my `.bash_profile`:

`export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Java/Home//bin"
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/directory-you-do-development-in
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

```
##
 # Your previous /Users/john/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/jonh/.bash_prof    ile.macports-saved_2014-02-09_at_13:58:24##

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-09_at_13:58:24: adding an appropriate PATH variable for u    se with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

##
# Your previous /Users/john/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/john/.bash_prof    ile.macports-saved_2014-02-09_at_14:02:11
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-09_at_14:02:11: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:$PATH
```

I know there is a temporary way `python3 -m pip install somepPackage` from official manual, but is there a way to change the install path permanently?